# how to solve error "the id value "weak_not related" occurs twice in the same by group in sas

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

may someone help me on this? I want to transpose the following data but in my trasnpose code exist errors;

my code is ;

```
proc transpose data=a out=b delimeter=_;
by k m;
id variable3 variable4 
var variable 5;
run;
```

my dataset is;

```
variable1   variable2    variable3     variable4        variable5   k     m
eye              eye1           weak      not related       1       1     1
eye              eye1           weak      not related      subj1    2     1
inf              inf1           weak      not related     2         1     2
inf              inf1           weak      not related     subj2     2     2
inf              inf1           weak      not related     subj1     2     2
inf              inf2           mod       not related     1         2     2
inf              inf2           mod       not related     subj1     3     2
```

and I want to be

```
variable1 variable2   weak_not_related   mod_not_related
eye              eye1            1
eye              eye1           subj1
inf              inf1            2 
inf              inf1          subj2
inf              inf1          subj1
inf              inf2                             1
inf              inf2                           subj1
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input variable1 $ variable2 $ variable3 $ variable4 $ 15 - 26 variable5 $ k m;
datalines;
eye eye1 weak not related 1     1 1 
eye eye1 weak not related subj1 2 1 
inf inf1 weak not related 2     1 2 
inf inf1 weak not related subj2 2 2 
inf inf1 weak not related subj1 2 2 
inf inf2 mod  not related 1     2 2 
inf inf2 mod  not related subj1 3 2 
;

data want;
   set have;
   if variable3 = 'weak' then weak_not_related = variable5;
   else if variable3 = 'mod' then mod_not_related = variable5;
   keep variable1 variable2 weak_not_related mod_not_related;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another variable to uniquely identify the groups you want to transpose.

First let's convert your listing into actual data.

```
data have;
  infile cards dsd ;
  input (variable1-variable5) (:$15.) k m;
cards;
eye,eye1,weak,not related,1,1,1
eye,eye1,weak,not related,subj1,2,1
inf,inf1,weak,not related,2,1,2
inf,inf1,weak,not related,subj2,2,2
inf,inf1,weak,not related,subj1,2,2
inf,inf2,mod,not related,1,2,2
inf,inf2,mod,not related,subj1,3,2
;
```

Now let's use BY group processing to number the rows in the groups.

```
data fix;
  set have;
  by variable1 variable2 ;
  row+1;
  if first.variable2 then row=1;
run;
```

Now we can transpose:

```
proc transpose data=fix out=want;
  by variable1 variable2 row ;
  id variable3 variable4 ;
  var variable5;
run;
```

Result

```
                                                 weaknot_    modnot_
Obs    variable1    variable2    row     _NAME_      related     related

 1        eye         eye1        1     variable5     1
 2        eye         eye1        2     variable5     subj1
 3        inf         inf1        1     variable5     2
 4        inf         inf1        2     variable5     subj2
 5        inf         inf1        3     variable5     subj1
 6        inf         inf2        1     variable5                 1
 7        inf         inf2        2     variable5                 subj1
```